# How to compile clk, the Android bootloader?

Tags: android, bootloader

https://github.com/n0d3/lk – this is the repository holding source code for [clk 1.5](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1114053), which is a bootloader for Android and which I am trying to compile. Compiled packages can be found; however, I need to customize it. How can I compile it?

Running  `make` returns the following:

```
$ make
makefile:22: *** No project specified.  Use "make projectname" or put "PROJECT := projectname" in local.mk.  Stop.
```

Running `make htcleo` returns the following:

```
$ make htcleo
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Domas/lk'
make[1]: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
LIBGCC =
CFLAGS = -O2 -g -fno-builtin -finline -W -Wall -Wno-multichar -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -include ./build-htcleo/config.h -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mlittle-endian -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb-interwork -mthumb -D__thumb__
including app/aboot dev/battery dev/fbcon dev/keys lib/debug lib/devinfo lib/heap lib/libc lib/ptable
generating build-htcleo/config.h
compiling arch/arm/start.S
make[1]: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
arch/arm/compile.mk:30: recipe for target 'build-htcleo/arch/arm/start.o' failed
make[1]: *** [build-htcleo/arch/arm/start.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Domas/lk'
makefile:15: recipe for target 'make-make' failed
make: *** [make-make] Error 2
```

As you can see the make breaks on `make[1]: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found`. I was able to compile an older version (which had a different compilation process) by using a CodeSourcery toolchain, which has `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe`, but not `arm-eabi-gcc.exe`, which seems to be needed to compile this version.

Note:
I appreciate that this might not be a popular type of question here on SO; however, I've been banging my head on this one the whole day, and could really use some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile it. What I did was find a git repository that had a compilation script and some additional files for compilation along side the source code,  but it was the old source code. So I downloaded this project, and replaced the source code with a recent one, and the compilation script worked. Below instructions, most of it is copy paste from [xda forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1114053#post14505387):

1. Download this zip archive here: https://github.com/cedesmith/cLK/archive/master.zip
   It's the old source code, but it has the necessary scripts to make compilation easy.
2. Unzip the archive so that the `compile` script's path is `~/cLK/compile`
3. Delete the `~/cLK/lk` subdirectory (this is the old source code).
4. Download the new source code: git clone https://github.com/n0d3/lk

Now you should have the new source code in `~/cLK/lk`. On to the actual compilation: this will depend on whether you're on Linux or Windows:

### Linux

1. on Debian:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gcc make git wget unzip zip libc6-dev-amd64 libc6-dev
   ```

   on Fedora:

   ```
   yum install gcc make git wget unzip zip
   ```
2. Now download the CodeSourcery toolchain:

   ```
   wget http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/package5353/public/arm-none-eabi/arm-2009q3-68-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
   tar xvfj arm-2009q3-68-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
   export PATH=$HOME/clk/arm-2009q3/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Finally, compile:

   ```
   cd ~/cLK
   ./compile clean
   ```

If everything goes well, you'll find the RUU_signed in this folder: `bin/RUU_signed.nbh`

### Windows

1. You'll need Cygwin:

   ```
   Download, the following file, and execute it http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe
   Click Next
   Click "Install from internet" and click Next
   Click Next (to accept the default directory to install)
   Click Next (to accept the default directory for local Package directory)
   Click "Direct Connection", and click Next
   Select a "local mirror", and click Next
   Now in the search bar, you need to search for the following things to install
   gcc
   make
   git
   wget
   zip
   unzip
   Once selected click Next to continue, and Finish
   ```
2. Fire up the cygwin terminal (mintty); the following commands probably don't work in cmd.exe.
3. Now download CodeSourcery toolchain and yang:

   ```
   wget http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/package5354/public/arm-none-eabi/arm-2009q3-68-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32.tar.bz2
   tar xvfj arm-2009q3-68-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32.tar.bz2
   wget http://htc-flasher.googlecode.com/files/yang-1.1_win32.zip
   cd cLK/bin
   rm -rf yang
   mkdir yang
   unzip ../../yang-1.1_win32.zip yang/yang.exe
   mv yang/yang.exe .
   cd ..
   sed -i s/yang/yang.exe/g compile
   ```
4. And finally, compile:

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/arm-2009q3/bin:$PATH
   cd ~/cLK
   ./compile clean
   ```

Now your RUU_signed.nbh will be located in the following folder `bin/RUU_signed.nbh`